Inheritance with Generics in Typescript - Type is not assignable
I am creating a generic parent class for several children. I want to create an abstract function in the parent class that accepts a matching child and returns again, that same class. This is what I came up with:
abstract class Parent<T> {
    constructor(public readonly val: T) { }
    public abstract add<C extends Parent<T>>(other: C): C;
}

Now here's the idea for my child class. You can see that it extends Parent<string> and takes in a Child and returns a Child.
class Child extends Parent<string> {
    public add(other: Child): Child {
        return new Child(this.val + other.val);
    }
}

Unfortunately I get this error on the add line:
Property 'add' in type 'Child' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Parent<string>'.
  Type '(other: Child) => Child' is not assignable to type '<C extends Parent<string>>(other: C) => C'.
    Type 'Child' is not assignable to type 'C'.
      'C' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Child'.ts(2416)

I don't understand this error. Child is literally extending Parent<string> exactly as shown in the error message. Now I also tried adding the type to the function signature:
class Child extends Parent<string> {
    public add<Child>(other: Child): Child {
        return new Child(this.val + other.val);
    }
}

And the error now shows up on the return line.
Type 'Child' is not assignable to type 'Child'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
  'Child' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Child'.ts(2719)

Can someone please explain why I am receiving these errors and what they mean?
A way to "fix" it for now is to simply remove the abstract function from Parent, although I'd like a more permanent fix for this. What are my options?
abstract class Parent<T> {
    constructor(public readonly val: T) { }
}


Generic functions and methods have their type arguments specified by callers, not implementers.  The Child class doesn’t call the method, it implements it. You need three generic type parameter on the class itself, not the method. You might be able to get away with using polymorphic this instead; when I get off mobile I’ll show how it works

Thanks, I'm interested to see what your solution is in this case.

So this playground link shows what's going on. Your original code and your solution below both have problems with unsound subclasses (see documentation for parameter bivariance.  The "correct" version of your code is to move C up to the class and have Parent<T, C extends Parent<T, C>>. That's type safe (but arguably too annoying to bother with). I could write up an answer explaining further if you wish.

Thank you - this explanation is excellent alongside your example. However, I noticed that new Child('a').add(new ProblemChild('b')); is allowed. The logic itself makes sense - since they both inherit Parent<string, ...>, but they are 2 different classes. Do you know why this is allowed?

I do know that but it's out of scope for this question; TS classes, like all of TS object types, are structurally typed, not nominally typed. Docs.  So what should I do here, write up an answer explaining all of this (except for the out-of-scope bit here)?

All right, I will set up another question for that. Would you like to re-post your answer as an official answer so I can accept it?

I will do so when I get a chance.

The problem with
abstract class Parent<T> {
  constructor(public readonly val: T) { }
  public abstract add<C extends Parent<T>>(other: C): C;
}

class Child extends Parent<string> {
  public add(other: Child): Child { // error for legitimate reason
    return new Child(this.val + other.val);
  }
}

is for generic functions and methods (like add()), the generic type parameters (like C) is scoped to the call signature. You specify the generic type argument by calling the method. You cannot do so by implementing the method.  The call signature <C extends Parent<T>>(other: C) => C means that whoever calls it decides what C will be.  Therefore you are saying that add() will allow any caller on any subclass to pass any subtype of Parent<T> in and the same type will come out. That's just... the identity function, and not what you're trying to express.
Note that if that were allowed, you could get runtime errors. For example:
class ProblemChild extends Parent<string> {
  problem = "definitely";
  public add(other: ProblemChild): ProblemChild { // error for legitimate reason
    return new ProblemChild(other.problem.toUpperCase());
  }
}

const c: Parent<string> = new ProblemChild("abc"); // error for legitimate reason
try {
  c.add(new Child("z")); // <-- this is allowed, but
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); // ERROR, other.problem is undefined 
}

}
If ProblemChild is allowed to implement add() by assuming its argument is another ProblemChild, and if every ProblemChild is also a Parent<string>, then you should be allowed to widen a ProblemChild to a Parent<string>, and then call add() with whatever subtype of Parent<string> you want, such as Child.  It is precisely this attempt to narrow the method parameter in subclasses which is inherently unsafe.  It is always safe to widen method parameters in subclasses, but not to narrow them.
That is: Functions and methods are contravariant in their parameter types, not covariant.  See Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript.

The type safe way to write your code is to move the scope of the generic from the method to the class itself.  So Parent<T, C>.add() instead of Parent<T>.add<C>(). That will allow each subclass to choose C. The implementer will choose, not the caller.  That looks like:
abstract class Parent<T, C extends Parent<T, C>> {
  constructor(public readonly val: T) { }
  public abstract add(other: C): C;
}

class Child extends Parent<string, Child> {
  public add(other: Child): Child {
    return new Child(this.val + other.val);
  }
}

This works because Child extends Parent<string, Child>.  Now you can still make a ProblemChild
class ProblemChild extends Parent<string, ProblemChild> {
  problem = "definitely";
  public add(other: ProblemChild): ProblemChild {
    return new ProblemChild(other.problem.toUpperCase());
  }
}

But TypeScript will complain when you try to call c.add(new Child("z")):
const c: Parent<string, ProblemChild> = new ProblemChild("abc");
try {
  c.add(new Child("z")); // <-- now we get the error we expected here
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); // ERROR, other.problem is undefined 
}

because a Parent<string, Child> is not a Parent<string, ProblemChild>.
Note the recursive constraint of the form class F<X extends F<X>>. This is known as F-bounded generics or for C++ folks, the curiously recurring template pattern. It comes up reasonably often in situations where subclasses need to specialize themselves the way you're doing here.
Sometimes in TypeScript you can avoid F-bounded generics by using the polymorphic this type but it won't work here because you can't be sure that new Child() will always result in this, as subclasses of Child might narrow things further.
Anyway, that's the safe way of doing it, but it's somewhat annoying, and is only preferable if you value type safety above ergonomics.

If you care more about ease of use than safety, then you can take advantage of the fact that methods in TypeScript have their parameters checked bivariantly (see the TS docs). This is unsafe but convenient.  Generics are checked more strictly, and non-method functions are usually checked more strictly (with --strictFunctionTypes enabled, anyway). But if you abandon generics and just use methods, TypeScript will let you narrow method parameters in subclasses with no error:
abstract class Parent<T> {
  constructor(public readonly val: T) { }
  public abstract add(other: Parent<T>): Parent<T>;
}

class Child extends Parent<string> {
  public add(other: Child): Child {
    return new Child(this.val + other.val);
  }
}

This is still just as unsafe as your original version, since all of this also compiles with no error, despite having the same runtime error as before:
class ProblemChild extends Parent<string> {
  problem = "definitely"; 
  public add(other: ProblemChild): ProblemChild { 
    return new ProblemChild(other.problem.toUpperCase());
  }
}

const c: Parent<string> = new ProblemChild("abc"); 
try {
  c.add(new Child("z")); 
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); // ERROR, other.problem is undefined 
}

So mostly it comes down to whether it's likely you'll write a ProblemChild like class or try to widen things to Parent before calling add(). If it's unlikely, then bivariance is convenient, and you just have to not be completely surprised if you hit a runtime error sometime in the future.
Playground link to code

Turns out, I don't need a generic in add at all. If the abstract function takes in and returns Parent<T>, it seems like child classes can override that with Child.
abstract class Parent<T> {
    constructor(public readonly val: T) { }
    public abstract add(other: Parent<T>): Parent<T>;
}

class Child extends Parent<string> {
    public add(other: Child): Child {
        return new Child(this.val + other.val);
    }
}


Yes you can do that because TS has bivariant methods. It isn’t type safe (I can show you how when I get off mobile) but it’s a common approach and apparently people don’t often make safety mistakes in practice with that pattern.  Generics are more strictly checked.
